# Expecting output is not displaying from php code

Tags: php, regex, string

This is the code:

```
<?php
$pattern =' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
$text = "kdaiuyq7e611422^^$^vbnvcn^vznbsjhf";

$text_split = str_split($text,1);
$data = '';
foreach($text_split as $value){
   if (preg_match("/".$value."/", $pattern )){
   $data = $data.$value;
   }
   if (!preg_match('/'.$value.'/', $pattern )){

     break;
   }
}
echo $data;
?>
```

Current output:

```
kdaiuyq7e611422^^$^vbnvcn^vznbsjhf
```

Expected output:

```
 kdaiuyq7e611422
```

Please help me editing my code error. In pattern there is no ^ or $. But preg_match is showing matched which is doubtful.

Comment: perhaps use `preg_quote($value)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You string `$text` have `^` which will match the begin of the string `$pattern`.

So the `preg_match('/^/', $pattern)` will return true, then the `^` will append to `$data`.

You should escape the `^` as a raw char, not a special char with `preg_match('/\^/', $pattern)` by the help of `preg_quote()` which will escape the special char.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to split your string up like that, the whole point of a regular expression is you can specify all the conditions within the expression. You can condense your entire code down to this:

```
$pattern = '/^[[:word:] ]+/';
$text = 'kdaiuyq7e611422^^$^vbnvcn^vznbsjhf';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Kris has accurately isolated that escaping in your method is the monkey wrench.  This can be solved with `preg_quote()` or wrapping pattern characters in `\Q` ... `\E` (force characters to be interpreted literally).

Slapping that bandaid on your method (as you have done while answering your own question) doesn't help you to see what you *should* be doing.

I recommend that you do away with the character mask, the `str_split()`, and the looped calls of `preg_match()`.  Your task can be accomplished far more briefly/efficiently/directly with a single `preg_match()` call.  Here is the clean way that obeys your character mask fully:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/846f8a3628e46e90b8044f961d078eecbdf95a5b))

```
$text = "kdaiuyq7e611422^^$^vbnvcn^vznbsjhf";
echo preg_match('/^[a-z\d ]+/i',$text,$out)?$out[0]:'No Match';
```

Output:

```
kdaiuyq7e611422
```

miknik's method was close to this, but it did not maintain 100% accuracy given your question requirements.  I'll explain:

`[:word:]` is a [POSIX Character Class](http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/regex/character-classes/) (functioning like `\w`) that represents letters(uppercase and lowercase), numbers, and an **underscore**.  Unfortunately for miknik, the underscore is not in your list of wanted characters, so this renders the pattern slightly inaccurate and may be untrustworthy for your project.